# Sending data from one jsp page to another jsp page

Tags: jsp

I am trying to send data from one jsp page to another jsp page using post method 
but it does not work. but if i can send the data by get method it works.i want to know why this happen.

first.jsp:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="second.jsp">
<input type='text' name='name'>
<input type="file"><input type='image' src='sfsdfsd.jpg'>
</form>
```

second.jsp

```
<%out.println(request.getParameter("name"));%>
```

Comment: first.jsp:<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="second.jsp"><input type='text' name='name'><input type="file"><input type='image' src='sfsdfsd.jpg'></form>

Comment: second.jsp<%out.println(request.getParameter("name"));%>

Answer (score 1):

> request.getParameter()

will return null when

> enctype="multipart/form-data"

is used.. please see this post for reference [How to upload files to server using JSP/Servlet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-to-server-using-jsp-servlet)